# Number of client consuming remote osgi service

Tags: osgi, dosgi

While playing with DOSGI I am trying to load balance the available remote osgi service.
I have gone through OSGi Service Platform Service Compendium 4.3 and found that we will need implement load balancing in toplogy manager...I am trying to figure out the load on particular
remote service like how many client is consuming that service to decide on my load balancing strategy ..I am new to OSGI and DOSGI so sorry if I missed something...

So basically I want to know how I can get that number if it is possible or is there any property to get that information like we have service.ranking to get ranking of the service.
Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information from the service hooks. However, if you need detailed information about the load I am not sure if the nr of clients is relevant, the latency invocations have seems much more relevant.

A way to measure this is to proxy the remote service an hide the original with the service hooks for other bundles. This is all quite advanced so it is too much to explain this in detail here. Consult the OSGi Core Specification 5.0.0 for details.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your response...I will do little bit more research will update my comment based on that.